# How to insert Japanese characters?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am writing a procedure with a simple insert statement. It will take @Target as parameter of type nvarchar(200) and this parameter will be inserted to table. 
My problem is how to insert Japanese character if parameter is receiving values like this - 'ンプライ'

```
INSERT INTO [TableName] (Target) VALUES (@Target)
```

using MS SQL Server 2008

Comment: You need to set the collation correctly on your database.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
insert into target (Target) values(N 'ンプライ')
```

Comment: How can I use N' with @Target

Comment: Thanks, it worked by prefixing the japanese string with N. As -> N'JapaneseText'

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your target datatype is `Nvarchar`

```
insert into TableName (Target) values (N 'ンプライ')
```

Comment: I am getting value in parameter, How can I use N' with @Target

Comment: Yes, table has column of type nvarchar and parameter type is also nvarchar

Comment: Unicode data type has n in type name like nchar, nvarchar and ntext.

Comment: SET @Target= N'ンプライ';